Would it take less thrust overall to put an object into higher orbit?
Obviously, the engineers put things up to LEO for a reason, but my understanding is that much of the burn is used in getting the object up to orbital velocity. Higher orbits are slower, but is the decrease in orbital velocity overwhelmed by the increase in thrust required to climb out of the gravity well?

As a simple counterexample, consider a satellite in LEO that brushes the atmosphere and sees its orbit begin to decay. If the resulting lower orbit had higher total energy, it would imply that air friction is somehow imparting energy to the satellite, despite the fact that it always opposes motion and results in a trajectory with lower potential energy.

A slower orbital speed does not mean less energy.  It means that a smaller fraction of the total energy is in kinetic form, but the sum of the kinetic and potential energy is greater.
Consider a typical launch to geosynchronous orbit via a Hohmann transfer.  To maintain an initial circular parking orbit with a radius of 6678 km (altitude 300 km), the required orbital speed is 7.7 km/s.  The target GEO orbit, a circle with a radius of 42164 km, requires a speed of 3 km/s. If you get to LEO altitude, but are only traveling at 3 km/s, you are not in an orbit, because you will quickly fall back down and crash into the Earth. If you stay in LEO at 7.7 km/s, you will never get to GEO. To do that, you have to apply thrust to increase the tangential speed.  The vis-viva equation
$$v^2=\mu\left(\frac{2}{r_1} - \frac{2}{r_1+r_2}\right)$$
says that to reach the desired apogee of the transfer, the perigee speed must increase to 10 km/s. Then, you turn the thrust off, and coast up to your apogee. This conserves angular momentum, so $v_2=r_1\, v_1 / r_2$, or 1.6 km/s.  In order to stay in orbit at that distance, you must add thrust again to bring the speed back up to 3 km/s.
That's what a gravity well is, and that's what climbing it means. Also note, in the transfer, all the thrust is applied not up, but sideways, tangential to the orbit.

While higher orbits are slower, it takes more energy to actually reach that height. It's a non-intuitive aspect of orbital mechanics - if you accelerate slowly to raise your orbit, you will actually slow down.
When an object is in a circular orbit, gravity centripetally accelerates the object, so gravitational acceleration and centripetal acceleration are equal.
$$a_{centripetal}={v^2\over r} =a_{gravity}= G{M \over r^2}$$
If you simplify this you get
$${v^2} = G{M \over r}$$
... and already you can see that if you raise your orbit (increase $r$ by some factor) you will need to decrease $v^2$ by the same factor to satisfy the equation.
To explain this more intuitively, consider the following figure...

If you start out in a circular orbit (inner circle above), and then increase your velocity quickly - say with a short burn of a powerful rocket (upper dot) - you will initially speed up, but this action will also change your circular orbit into an elliptical one. You will be going faster at the perigee (upper dot) of this elliptical orbit than you were in the original circular orbit, but then as you coast up to the apogee (lower dot) of the elliptical orbit you will end up travelling even slower than when you started.
If you want to circularize the elliptical orbit while you are at its apogee (lower dot), you will need to speed up again. If you accelerate by the right amount, you will change your elliptical orbit into another circular orbit (outer circle) with a higher altitude than the original circular orbit. However, despite the fact that you sped up twice, you will end up travelling slower in this new circular orbit than in your original circular orbit. This happens because you lost more speed coasting "uphill" from the perigee to the apogee of the elliptical orbit than the sum of the speed you gained with the two burns of your rocket.
Now if you imagine making hundreds of tiny burns all around the planet, or just executing a weeks-long continuous burn with a low thrust engine, such as a hall effect thruster, the burns and the effect of coasting from perigee to apogee will all seem to blur together. The net effect will appear to be that you accelerated and yet ended up going slower than when you started.
(Figure courtesy of Starlink)



Would it take less thrust overall to put an object into higher orbit?

I think that you are confusing thrust with velocity. Thrust is the amount of engine force pushing on the vehicle, and will determine how quickly your speed increases (and if it increases at all). Velocity is how it is going in a certain direction. Simply going to a higher orbit isn't going to make the amount of thrust go down.

my understanding is that much of the burn is used in getting the object up to orbital velocity.

Correct

is the decrease in orbital velocity overwhelmed by the increase in thrust required to climb out of the gravity well?

No. It would take the amount of thrust required to put it into LEO, and then additional thrust to place it into the higher orbit.
A great way to simulate this is KSP (Kerbal Space Program). Reaching a low orbit around Kerbin takes about 3400 m/s of Delta V. There is (outside of cheating/glitches) no way to reach a significantly higher orbit with significantly less Delta V used.
If you don't have KSP, you can play around with an online calculator, like this KSP Delta V Planner

Thank you. I'm going to just have to do the math. What I'm really trying to figure out is if you save fuel going directly into (for instance) geosync instead of going into LEO, then taking a Hohmann up to geosync. (and, if so, how much). Kerbal might just be the way to go.

@RobertRapplean: IIRC it depends on how much thrust you have. With a high-thrust rocket, you can indeed save a little bit of delta-v by launching straight up to (e.g.) geosync altitude and circularizing there, as compared to first circularizing into low orbit and then raising the orbit from there. But with low (read: realistic) thrust, launching straight up becomes inefficient due to gravity losses, and you instead want to turn sideways as soon as possible and circularize as low as you can before raising your apogee (possibly over several orbits to take full advantage of the Oberth effect).

+1 for the KSP reference.  It really is one of the best tools around for a layperson (or even some pros apparently) to get an better understanding of orbital mechanics.  Also, obligatory xkcd... https://xkcd.com/1356

In addition to KSP, there's also Universe Sandbox 2 if you want simulate changes to the solar system or larger scales

For this reason, it is useful to write things in the form of Specific orbital energy.
An object has two relevant forms of energy (with just classical mechanics):
The kinetic energy and the potential gravitational energy.
$E = E_k + E_p$
We use the specific energies so we don't have to multiple by all the masses, and the equations are generalized for "any" object in such an orbit. Wikipedia shows clearly how the two energies can be written then:


Where

v is the orbital speed
r is the orbital distance between bodies;
mu = G(m_1 + M_2) is the sum of the standard gravitationsal parameters
h is the specific relatie angular momentum
e is the orbital eccentricity
a is the semi major access.


As one can see this specific energy in the end only depends on mu (which is a constant for any two body, it is not influenced by velocity or distance).
It is only influenced by the semi major axis.
So the higher the semi major axis the higher the specific orbital energy (notice it's always negative, 0 being the exact point we just achieved escape velocity "infinite long semi major axis").
In conclusion: the energy to get "higher" is more than the energy to get faster.
The thing is: that we don't need to get much higher, only 100km, while we are already 6371 km "away". However we're not at a stable orbit with that semi major axis, we're almost at standstill.
if earth would compress to a point mass, we would be in a very high eccentric orbit with a semi major axis of roughly 3186 km.
